# R clip raster with multiple bands

Tags: r, crop, subset, raster, r-raster

I want to create a subset of an image with four bands. Therefore I am using the crop function in R.

```
A<-raster("L8_stacked.tif")
subset<-extent(c(639451, 660104, 5469254, 5489566))
B<-crop(A,subset)
```

As a result I get a raster with only one band in the .tif file. Do I have to define other options to get a subset image with 4 bands?

Comment: What do you get for `B` in your workspace?  (and for that matter, have you verified that `A` contains the four bands/layers you expect?)

Comment: A itself has only one band. Try nlayers(A) - right?  Start with brick("L8_stacked.tif") and then crop that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the others already pointed out in the comments, the `raster()` function returns a (single) RasterLayer object. If you want a multilayer raster object you need to use the `stack()` or `brick()` function load the image into R. I.e.:

```
A <- stack("L8_stacked.tif")
```

If you then apply your extent with the `crop()` function, the result should be a raster stack containing all the bands from the original image.

To learn more on the raster package, read this [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf).